# ui-router. get state name from object/function

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

I wonder, is there any way to reference states in view with object or function?

Just to decouple views from states definition. E.g. if I change state name I don't have to change it everywhere in my views.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

One solution, described below, could be found here, as a working [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/pujRy9eUeHnZInPuXT23?p=preview)

In this example we will define state for some entity (e.g. employee) like:

1. **list** view and
2. **detail** view.

Let's use some variable `entityName` to play the role of the decoupled naming:

```
var entityName = "employee";

$stateProvider
    .state(entityName, {
        url: '/' + entityName,
        views: {
          ...
      }})

    .state(entityName + '.detail', {
        url: '/{{Id}}',
        views: {
          ...
      }});
```

Navigation from the list to the detail view *(As we can see, there is no explicit "employee" name used)*:

```
<a ui-sref="{{detailLink(item)}}" >{{item.Name}}</a>
```

Next we have to define the `detailLink(item)`. We will do it directly in the `controller` here, but it could be some `ListModel` instance instead, encapsulating more operations *(paging, sorting)*, including the `detailLink`.

```
controller:['$scope','$state',
  function ( $scope , $state){ 

      $scope.detailLink = function (item){

          // here we get the employee in run-time
          var currentState = $state.current.name; 
          var sref = currentState + '.detail({Id:' + item.Id + '})';
          return sref;
      };
}],
```

And that's it. It could be even more complex... The complete example code *(enclosed below as states defintion)* could be found and run [here](http://plnkr.co/edit/pujRy9eUeHnZInPuXT23?p=preview)

```
.config(['$stateProvider',
function( $stateProvider) {

    var entityName = "employee";

    $stateProvider
      .state(entityName, {
        url: '/' + entityName,
        views: {
          body: {
          template: '<div>' +
                    '  <h2>List View</h2> ' +
                    '  <ul ng-repeat="item in items"> ' +
                    '   <li><a ui-sref="{{detailLink(item)}}" >{{item.Name}}</a>' +
                    '  </li></ul>' +
                    '  <h2>Detail View</h2> ' +
                    '  <div ui-view="detail"></div>' +
                    '</div>',
          controller:['$scope','$state',
            function ( $scope , $state){ 

              $scope.items = [{Name : "Abc", Id : 0}, {Name : "Def", Id : 1}];

              $scope.detailLink = function (item){

                 var currentState = $state.current.name;
                 return currentState + '.detail({Id:' + item.Id + '})';
              };
          }],
        }
      }})
      .state(entityName + '.detail', {
        url: '/{{Id}}',
        views: {
          detail: {
          template: '<div>' +
                    '  <label>{{item.Name}} ' +
                    '  <input ng-model="item.Name"}}" type="text" />' +
                    '  <div>current state name: <i>{{state.name}}<i></div> ' +
                    '</div>',
          controller:['$scope','$stateParams','$state',
            function ( $scope , $stateParams , $state){ 
              $scope.state = $state.current
              $scope.item = $scope.items[$stateParams.Id];
          }],
        }
      }});

}])
```

Comment: Great if that helped ;) `ui-router` is a great choice!