# How to get the current state name using angularjs

Tags: angularjs

I want to get the current state name in my run(). I am using $state.current.name. but its returning empty string.

```js
$rootScope.$on('$stateChangeStart', function (event, next) {            
            var json = (function () {
                event.preventDefault();
                $.ajax({
                    'async': false,
                    'global': false,
                    'url':'users/testLogin',
                    //'data': 'action=showOrders', 
                    'dataType': "json",
                    'success': function (data) {
                        if(data.success){
                            $rootScope.authenticated = true;
                            $rootScope.id = data.data.id;
                            $rootScope.unique_id = data.data.unique_id;
                            $rootScope.print_house_id = data.data.print_house_id;
                            $rootScope.name = data.data.name;
                            $rootScope.email = data.data.email; 
                            $rootScope.type = data.data.type; 
                        } else {
                            console.log($state.current.name);

                        }                        
                    }
                });
            })(); 
        });
```

Can anyone please find out where is my error.

Comment: Possible duplicate of : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23590799/ui-router-get-state-name-from-object-function

Comment: first, you should use angular `$http` rather than jquery `$.ajax` here;  secondly, it doesn't look like you injected `$state` into this method.  Also, using `$rootScope` like this is an anti-pattern.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use this,

```
$rootScope.$on('$stateChangeStart', function (event, toState, toParams, fromState, fromParams) {

         $state.current = toState;   // if you need the target Url
          $state.current = fromState;// If you need the current URL
        var json = (function () {
            event.preventDefault();
            $.ajax({
                'async': false,
                'global': false,
                'url':'users/testLogin',
                //'data': 'action=showOrders', 
                'dataType': "json",
                'success': function (data) {
                    if(data.success){
                        $rootScope.authenticated = true;
                        $rootScope.id = data.data.id;
                        $rootScope.unique_id = data.data.unique_id;
                        $rootScope.print_house_id = data.data.print_house_id;
                        $rootScope.name = data.data.name;
                        $rootScope.email = data.data.email; 
                        $rootScope.type = data.data.type; 
                    } else {
                        console.log($state.current.name);//It should show value now

                    }                        
                }
            });
        })(); 
    })
```

Comment: `$state` is a service provided by ui-router, it should never be necessary to manually set any of it's values.....

Comment: @Claies I have updated my answer. You are correct. But I manually set because it is not clear which state name he needs.

Comment: if you are manually setting a value, you should probably be using a different variable name so as not to confuse this value with a value that is legitimately being provided by the service of that name.

Comment: @Claies you are again right. Not thought that. Thanks for pointing.

Comment: Thanx for ur ans. but it still not showing my current state.